# Adobe Acrobat 2017 Javascript is null?

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

In this code:

```
this.getField("myField").value == null;
this.getField("myField").value === null;
typeof this.getField("myField").value == null;
typeof this.getField("myField").value === null;
this.getField("myField").rawValue === null;
this.getField("myField").formattedValue === "";
this.getField("myField").isNull;
this.getField("myField").isNull == True;
```

all of the above exchanging 'null' for 'Null', encapsulated 'Null', and 'undefined'.

In each circumstance all I get is:

```
TypeError: this.getField(...) is null
23:Field:Blur
```

How do I see if a field is null? I do not want to have default values because not every field on the form needs to be used and should be able to be blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally... meaning you used an application rather than a library to create the form... PDF field values will never be null. An empty field has a zero-length string as the default value. To test if the field is empty use...

```
if (this.getField("myField").value.length == 0) {
    // do something 
}
else {
    // it has a value
}
```

or

```
if (this.getField("myField").value == "") {
    // do something 
}
else {
    // it has a value
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The key for Acrobat was the field.value.length, not just field.length like I was trying.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting that error, it's because `this.getField("myField")` **itself** is returning `null`. So **any** attempt to use a property on what it returns will fail.

It sounds like you need a `null` guard:

```
var field = this.getField("myField");
if (field !== null) }
    // use `field.value` here...
}
```

Comment: I just tried that approach...

    console.show();var checkNull = this.getField("myField");
    if(checkNull !== null){
    }else{
    console.println("It has to be null...");
    }

Here's the output:

    TypeError: this.getField(...) is null
    23:Field:Blur

Comment: @blainechristian - That's **very** strange. Normal JavaScript doesn't behave that way, must be some weird Adobe thing (or the error is from different code).